# Hiding Rows that do not Have Values VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a macro that goes through a list and hides a row if there are no values in any of the columns of that row. However, the data already has hidden columns from another macro. Here's my attempt below, which doesn't seem to do anything as of yet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub HideRowsMenu()
    BeginRow = 5 'Start after Master Menu item
    EndRow = 731 'Filter all rows in sheet (about 730)
    ColumnsWithValues = 0 'Counter for number of columns in a row that have a value. If 0, hide the row.
    ColumnStart = 2 'Start where you  have group values
    ColumnEnd = 50 'Maximum number of groups

    RowNumber = 0
    ColumnNumber = 0

    'Outer loop cycles through all the rows of range, inner cycles through the columns to check values
    For RowNumber = BeginRow To EndRow
        ColumnsWithValues = 0 'Reset counter to 0 to avoid counting last row's values

        For ColumnNumber = ColumnStart To ColumnEnd
            'If given cell index is empty (0) and the cell is not previously hidden, add 1 to the counter
            If Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber).Value = 0 And Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber).Columns.Hidden = False Then
                ColumnsWithValues = ColumnsWithValues + 1
            End If
        Next ColumnNumber

        'After going through all the columns of a row, check if there were any column with values. If not, then hide the row
        If ColumnsWithValues = 0 Then
            Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    'Repeat for all rows
    Next RowNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would not something like this work? (untested)

```
'## Declare a range variable to represent the current row'
Dim rowRange as Range
For RowNumber = BeginRow To EndRow
    '# Set the range variable, only the VISIBLE cells'
    Set rowRange = Range(Cells(RowNumber, ColumnStart), Cells(RowNumber, ColumnEnd)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    '# use magic to determine if there are any values in this row
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rowRange) = 0 Then
        rowRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next RowNumber
```

Comment: I tried to edit the code but it says changing one part wasnt enough lol.  Your code works I tested it but you need to update this your set rowrange to

    Set rowRange = Range(Cells(RowNumber, ColumnStart), Cells(RowNumber, ColumnEnd)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: It appears that this works perfectly. Thanks for your help. I was thinking of doing it based on selecting a range, but was unsure how to differentiate visible/not.

Comment: You're welcome! If it has solved the problem, do mark the answer as "Accepted."  Cheers!

Comment: Also yes to the above comment, there was a period where there should have been a comma.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and fixed it now :)