# Hide row having no value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying the solution from [Hiding Rows that do not Have Values VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997009/hiding-rows-that-do-not-have-values-vba)

Code (Not working for me):

```
Dim rowRange As Range
    BeginRow = 2 'Start after Master Menu item
    EndRow = 252 'Filter all rows in sheet (about 730)
    ColumnsWithValues = 0 'Counter for number of columns in a row that have a value. If 0, hide the row.
    ColumnStart = 2 'Start where you  have group values
    ColumnEnd = 9 'Maximum number of groups
    RowNumber = 0
    ColumnNumber = 0
For RowNumber = BeginRow To EndRow
    Set rowRange = Range(Cells(RowNumber, ColumnStart), Cells(RowNumber, ColumnEnd)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rowRange) = 0 Then
        rowRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    'Repeat for all rows
    Next RowNumber
End Sub
```

My workbook

[image: My WOrkbook]

Gives error 104; No cell found.

Where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpecialCells` raises an error if no matching cells are found - you can ignore that using `On Error Resume Next` and then test to see if `rowRange` was set:

```
    Dim rowRange As Range
    BeginRow = 2 'Start after Master Menu item
    EndRow = 252 'Filter all rows in sheet (about 730)
    ColumnsWithValues = 0 'Counter for number of columns in a row 
                          'that have a value. If 0, hide the row.
    ColumnStart = 2 'Start where you  have group values
    ColumnEnd = 9 'Maximum number of groups
    RowNumber = 0
    ColumnNumber = 0
    For RowNumber = BeginRow To EndRow
        Set rowRange = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rowRange = Range(Cells(RowNumber, ColumnStart), _
                      Cells(RowNumber, ColumnEnd)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error Goto 0

        If Not rowRange Is Nothing Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rowRange) = 0 Then
                rowRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
        'Repeat for all rows
    Next RowNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I am novice in excel. code Still gives error. Object required on NotrowRange. I Don't Understand this so can't figure out.

Comment: On changing notrowrange = rowrange it throws invalid call or procedure error. Checking. I must be missing something.

Comment: My typo `NotrowRange Is Nothing` >> `Not rowRange Is Nothing`

Comment: Tried but not working. Think something wrong with my excel.